# Aumentar ID a "tr" en Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Lo que ocurre es que hago un CRUD con mostrando con datatable, cada vez que agrego un nuevo campo, agrega, pero sin embargo el `tr` que se ha agregado no tiene `id` la cual necesito para poder eliminar la fila `tr`

**Eliminar**

```
tabla.row($("tr[id=" + id + "]")).remove().draw(false);
```

**Agregar**

```
         var row=tabla.row.add([
            msg.lines_product.description,
            msg.description,
            msg.abreviation,
            function (data, type, row, meta) {
                if (msg.status === 0) { return '<span class="label label-danger">In Activo</span>' }
                if (msg.status === 1) { return '<span class="label label-success">Activo</span>' }
                if (msg.status === 2) { return '<span class="label label-warning">Bloqueado</span>' }
            },
            function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return '<a class="btn btn-warning" onclick="bsl(' + msg.id + ')" href="#"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a><a href = "#" onclick = "remove(' + msg.id +')" class="btn btn-danger"> <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>';
            }
        ]).draw();
```

utilizé `$(row).attr('id', msg.id);` pero no agrega nada, las tablas estan distribuidas con `td`

necesito saver como agrego `id` a la nueva fila que se va a agregar o eliminar `tr` via `parent` al hacer click en un boton

Answer (score 1):

Te sirve: https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow

```
"createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
  $(row).attr(id', 'algun valor' );
}
```

Es un atributo más de la definición de la datatable. Aquí `data` es la información que pasaste a `tabla.row.add([])`. Solo que estas limitado a la info que pasaste como parámetro. Igual te sirve